howto install targets recursively in cmake
I would have expected the following to work recursively through the target dependency hierarchy:
add_executable(myexec ...)
target_link_library (
         myexec 
         PRIVATE some_library_created_via_target)
install (
         TARGETS myexec
         RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
         DESTINATION ./bin
         COMPONENT myexec)

So when I call
cmake --install builddir --component myexec

I would expect following result:
ls bin
myexec
some_library_created_via_target.so

But what I get is:
ls bin
myexec
libc.so
and some other libraries which I expect to be part of the operating system

shure, myexec dependes on stdc.so but that is not what I need to be installed. I need the some_library_created_via_target.so file installed along with my myexec file.
The following works though (here I list all dependencies in the TARGETS list, not only myexec):
add_executable(myexec ...)
target_link_library (
    myexec 
    PRIVATE some_library_created_via_target)
install (
    TARGETS myexec some_library_created_via_target
    DESTINATION ./bin
    COMPONENT myexec)

This solution is unsatisfactory because if the target dependency hierarchy is deep, then I do not easily see which targets I have to add to install(TARGETS ...)
Is there another way?
